# can`t select CSS parent selector element

Tags: css

I have a paragraph and inside the p an iframe

```
p > iframe {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
} 

iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

How to select the iframe parent (ONLY that p) in css - without javascript

The method above `p > iframe` doesn`t work. I want to add different style to paragraph and iframe.

Comment: You don't. It's not possible to apply rules on elements based on complex content (only some basic `:empty`, etc, pseudoselectors).

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. If you want to apply a CSS rule on the parent `p` you can put simply `p { ... }`. It's not possible, however, to apply this rule only if the p has an iframe within it.

Comment: Try using classes. Give iframe `class="my-frame"` and with CSS, `p .my-iframe`. Check in developer console if the style is applied. I would use `<div>` around iframe for setting height/width, and iframe to fill the div.

Comment: @DmitriyKravchuk the video is inserted by the user using summernote plugin and the iframe is inserted in a p element. The content is then grab from DB into the view - that`s why i need a css to custom the view

Comment: CSS 3 does not currently support parent selection.  Unfortunately.

Comment: let's say if i want to use JQuery `$("iframe").parent().addClass('iframe_p');` is not working eather ( where iframe_p class is the p > iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Style the p element in itself and then the iframe with what you want differently.

Your notation p > iframe is calling upon all iframes that are within a p. So in the example the impact of iframe is the same as for p > iframe.

Comment: yes but my content is dynamic